# Text input won't work

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

I have this form in which if this one option is selected, then a specific text input will pop up. I don't know why, but when I select **Phone**, the text input that pops up won't let me write anything on it.

Here's the code:

```js
function checkType() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
  var emailType = document.getElementById('emailType');
  var phoneType = document.getElementById('phoneType');

  if (email.checked) {
    emailType.style.opacity = "1";
    emailType.style.height = "3em";

    phoneType.style.opacity = "0";
    phoneType.style.height = "0";
  } else if (phone.checked) {
    emailType.style.opacity = "0";
    emailType.style.height = "0";

    phoneType.style.opacity = "1";
    phoneType.style.height = "3em";
  }

}

function showMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var myForm = event.target;
  myForm.style.opacity = "0";
  myForm.style.height = "0";
  myForm.style.transition = ".5s";


  document.getElementById('submitted').style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById('submitted').style.transition = "2s";
}


document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener("submit", showMessage);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/*Navigation Styles*/

nav {
  background-color: #AC3931;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

nav a {
  color: #f6f7eb;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*I made the links' font size in the nav bar bigger. I thought it was too small. I hope that's okay*/

nav li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}


/*Navigation Styles end*/


/*Header Styles*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #E18335;
  line-height: .2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}


/*Header styles end*/

.pgh {
  color: black;
}


/*Images Styles*/

.logo-image {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px #beb7a4;
  height: 111px;
  width: 115px;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 960px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
}

.img3 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
}

.img4 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
}

.socialIcon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.contactImage {
  height: 350px;
  width: 450px;
}


/*Images Styles end*/

#content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

#sec1 {
  padding: 10px;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color: #FBFFB9;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sec3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

#calmFont {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

#intenseFont {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
}

.leftcol {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.rightcol {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nameClassCopy {
  float: left;
}

.socialIcons {
  float: right;
}

footer {
  background-color: #AC3931;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFBC42;
}

#emailType {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

#phoneType {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

#contactPgh {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#normalFont {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#submit {
  background-color: #AC3931;
  border-radius: 15px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #ccc;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: #FFBC42;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Dry Oar | Contact Us</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <header>
      <img class="logo-image" alt="Logo Picture" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2Fdryoarlogo%20copy%202.png?1526759445079">
      <br>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>&nbsp;<a href="index.html">| Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="rivers.html">| Rivers</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html">| Contact Us &nbsp; |</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <br>
      <img class="banner-image" alt="Banner" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2FredContactBanner.jpg?1531435849381">
      <br>

    </header>
    <div id="normalFont">
      <br>
      <section id="sec3" class="clearfix">
        <h1 style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;">
          Need more information?
        </h1>
        <p id="contactPgh">
          Questions about pricing, location, equipment rental, scheduling or anything else?! Let us know!
        </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Section Two -->
      <section id="sec1" class="clearfix">


        <!-- Left column -->
        <div class="leftcol" style="border-right: 1px solid gray;">
          <form id="myForm">

            First Name:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Arthur" required>
            <br>
            <br> Last Name:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Figueiredo" required>
            <br>
            <br> Do you prefer to be contacted by e-mail or phone?
            <br>

            <input type="radio" name="contactType" id="email" onclick="checkType()"> <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2Femail-icon.png?1531433209873"> E-Mail
            <br>

            <input type="radio" name="contactType" id="phone" onclick="checkType()"> <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2Fphone-icon.png?1531433375571"> Phone
            <br>
            <div id="emailType">

              E-Mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="text" placeholder="example@email.com">

            </div>


            <div id="phoneType">
              Phone number:
              <input type="text" placeholder="(111)222-3333">
            </div>

            Your Message:
            <br>
            <br>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" placeholder="Your message here . . ." required></textarea>

            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
          </form>
          <div id="submitted" style="opacity: 0">
            <h2>Thank you for contacting us</h2>
            <p>We will get back to you shortly.</p>
          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Right column -->
        <div class="rightcol">
          <img class="contactImage" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2FcontactLast.png?1531436124712">


        </div>
      </section>



      <br>

    </div>
    <footer class="clearfix">
      <hr>
      <div class="NameClassCopy">
        &copy; Dry Oar 2018 || Arthur Figueiredo WDD 100‐02
      </div>

      <div class="socialIcons">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="socialIcon" alt="Facebook Page" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2FFacebookYellow.png?1531436293112"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="socialIcon" alt="Youtube Channel" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2FyoutubeYellow.png?1531436475201"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="socialIcon" alt="WhatsApp" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/3ee5b53d-8bb9-4b30-876e-0162812b3a1e%2FwppYellow.png?1531436410371"></a>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, when I select phone and just type something, it won't go into the phone text input box, but when I click on the Email option, whatever I typed will be on its text input box.

I've tried making the email text input disabled if the phone option is selected, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would really help if you pressed the Create Code Snippet button.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: The problem is that changing the height of the DIV doesn't make the input inside it go away. So both inputs are at the same place, and when you try to select the phone input you're actually selecting the email input.

Comment: Try setting `display: none;` on the input inside the DIV when you make the DIV disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the from opacity to `display:none` still doesn't solve his actual problem. From the code above, he is trying to access a DOM object which is not defined. This would cause Javascript to return an error of `undefined`. Simply define the `emailType` and `phoneType` within your script and see it done bro.
What i mean is this:

```
var emailType = document.getElementById('emailType');
```

and

```
var phoneType = document.getElementById('phoneType');
```

just add these two lines before the `if(` conditions.
You can now choose whether or not to use opacity or not......

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of codes can solve this problems:

```js
if (email.checked) {
  document.getElementById("phoneType").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("emailType").style.display = "";
  emailType.style.opacity = "1";
  emailType.style.height = "3em";
} else if (phone.checked) {
  document.getElementById("emailType").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("phoneType").style.display = "";

  phoneType.style.opacity = "1";
  phoneType.style.height = "3em";
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, using  xx.style.opacity = "0" to control a <input> is not a good way.